# Can I say "no sooner than in the first week of May"?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

> I will start no sooner than in the first week of May.

Is that correct? I am not sure because I could not find any similar sentences with weeks or months.
I would like to say that I cannot start until the first week of May.

Comment: It's grammatical, but sounds a bit strange. I would either drop the *in* or add *sometime* in front of it. (Although I think just dropping it is better since it's less wordy.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"No sooner" means *not earlier*. So, the sentence is not wrong.
You can use it with week, month, day, morning or any other time period.